# Calculate the standard deviation of $Y=X+\frac{(X-k)^2}{a}$, knowing the standard deviation of $X$

Tags: random-variables, standard-deviation

Let $\mu$ be the expected value of random variable $X$ with density $f(x)$. The standard deviation of $X$ is defined as
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\sigma_X &\equiv {\sqrt {\operatorname {E} \left[(X-\mu )^{2}\right]}}\end{aligned}}}$$
I would like to know if it is possible to express the standard deviation of the random variable $Y$, defined as:
$$Y=X+\frac{(X-k)^2}{a}$$
(where $a$ and $k$ are constants) starting from $\sigma_X$.

Edit. Let us suppose to know all the n-th moment $E[X^n]$

Comment: Due to the $X^2$ term, the answer will require information about the fourth moment $E[X^4]$ of $X$.

Comment: Yes, we could suppose to know also the fourth moment of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that if you know all the moments:

$$\sigma_Y^2 = \langle Y^2 \rangle - \langle Y \rangle^2.$$

Since $Y$ and $Y^2$ are polynomials in $X$, this can be expressed in terms of expectations of positive integer powers of $X$. Note the common result that for any random variable,

$$\langle (X - \langle X \rangle)^2 \rangle = \langle X^2 - 2 X \langle X \rangle + \langle X \rangle^2 \rangle= \langle X^2 \rangle - \langle X \rangle^2$$

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your answer. Could you write the expression of standard deviation of Y, please? I would like to learn how to write It.

Comment: @Mark Hi. What parts do you follow? What are you struggling with? Can you write out $Y$ and $Y^2$ as standard-form polynomials in $X$? Can you then apply the formula for $\sigma_Y$ that I gave? You said that you can take $E[X^n]$ as given: note that this is $\langle X^n \rangle$.